# RegEx: Finding a pattern followed by another pattern with a gap

Tags: regex

I've a file containing hundreds of SQL Insert statements. I want to identify only those statements start with HTML paragraph tag `<p>` but doesn't have an ending para tag `</p>`.

I'm trying on these lines

```
<p>[^\n]*(?!</p>) <-- a <p> followed by any number of characters until \n and then </p>
```

This does not work. Below is the sample data

```
INSERT INTO `help` VALUES 
(1,1,'<p>Radiotherapy uses a beam of high&#45;energy rays (or particles) lymph nodes.</p>'),
(2,1,'<p>EBRT delivers radiation from a machine outside the body. '),
(3,1,'<p>Following lumpectomy radiotherapy <ul><li>Heading</li></ul></p>'),
```

Ideally, I would be appending a `</p>` where they are not present e.g. in the insert statement #2.

Comment: Is the closing `</p>` always going to be immediately prior to `')`?

Comment: What language or tool are you using

Comment: Updated my answer with working solution.

Comment: @Sepster No. It could be in between the statement.

Comment: @justintime Java and JavaScript

Comment: In the regex above `[^\n]*`  walks other any non newline including `</p>`  taking you to the end of the line. At that point the negative '(?!</p>)' matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use this:

`(\(\d+,\d+,'<p>.*?)(</p>)?('\),)`

You'll get back-references to the following parts:

1. `(1,1,'<p>Radiotherapy uses a beam of high&#45;energy rays (or particles) lymph nodes.` <-- ie the preamble, and body text including the opening P tag
2. `</p>` <-- The optional closing P tag.. ie you might not get a match for 2.
3. `'),` <-- the closing quote and parenthesis, and trailing comma

You can then replace this with:

`$1</p>$3` (eg using .NET style backreferences).

ie, rebuild the string with each of your backreferences, with an explicit closing P tag regardless of if one was found or not.

Without knowing your platform, I can't give you the correct regex replace syntax for this.

In .NET it would be:

```
string input = @"INSERT INTO `help` VALUES 
(1,1,'<p>Radiotherapy uses a beam of high&#45;energy rays (or particles) lymph nodes.</p>'),
(2,1,'<p>EBRT delivers radiation from a machine outside the body. '),
(3,1,'<p>Following lumpectomy radiotherapy <ul><li>Heading</li></ul></p>'),";

Regex r = new Regex(@"(\(\d+,\d+,'<p>.*?)(</p>)?('\),)");
string output = r.Replace(input, "$1</p>$3");

Console.Write(output);
```

Which produces this output:

```
INSERT INTO `help` VALUES
(1,1,'<p>Radiotherapy uses a beam of high&#45;energy rays (or particles) lymph nodes.</p>'),
(2,1,'<p>EBRT delivers radiation from a machine outside the body. </p>'),
(3,1,'<p>Following lumpectomy radiotherapy <ul><li>Heading</li></ul></p>'),
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got how this works.
I am using RegEx Buddy and other tools like Notepad++ and don't want to particularly write code to do this. This is one time thing and I just wanted a way to identify and replace the patterns.
I'm not sure if replacing the .Net style works in RegEx Buddy or Notepad++. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @Ali it looks like Notepad++ doesn't do the optional `(</p>)?` capture.  Replace string might be eg `\1</p>\3` (ie backslash, not dollar sign).  Should've said you were using those tools at the outset! ;-)  Send me the SQL file and I'll fix it, if you like?  sepster at internode dot on dot net

Answer (score 1):

If you can be sure the `</p>` is always followed by a quote `'` the following works in Perl (don't have notepad++ )

```
/<p> [^\n]* (?<! <\/p> )  (?=') /gx
```

(the /x allows spaces for clarity).  This is doing a negative lookbehind that is anchored on a lookahead for the quote.

Comment: No it is not always followed by a quote but your solution gave me some more ideas. Thanks